# get public posts of any user from facebook in asp.net + c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is it possible to retrieve posts of a user from asp.net + c# ?
I have tried https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=ABC&type=post but it returns different results than expected.
I also tried through creating an app in app center but it allows only self posts.

Comment: If it is possible then I hate FB even more ...

Comment: You need to obtain permissions from the user whose information you are trying to access. That is, you need to log in and get an access token, then use that when querying the graph API. See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/getting-started/graphapi/ for more info.

Comment: i have acquired access token but i'm unable to retrieve the posts